# Enforce one of two columns not be NULL with Entity Framework 6

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a table like the following:

```
[Table("tblStore")]
public class Store
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Option1 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Option2 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

I need to enforce that either Option1 or Option2 be specified (not null).  Can someone please suggest a way to do that with EF 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do one trick: add new property to your POCO class, that will be result of concatenation of `Option1` and `Option2` and set to this property(let call it `Options`) attribute `[Required]`. Of course, we need to remove this attribute from `Option1` and `Option2` properties to make it possible assign to them `null` values. Now, if `Option1` and `Option2` will not have values, `Options` also will be blank and due to `[Required]` attribute on it, EF's error will be thrown, when you will attempt to insert this entity into database:

```
public class Store
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Option1 { get; set; }        
    public string Option2 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Options { get { return Option1 + Option2; } private set { } }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Good enough for me!  Thanks!